# Why does casting a column of pandas Timestamps convert them to datetime.datetime objects (and why do they lose their timezone)?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

A dataframe contains 1 column of Timestamps and one column of integers (just along for the ride - to prevent anything thinking it was just a Series).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[(pd.Timestamp.utcnow()+pd.Timedelta(hours=1)) for i in range(3)],
          'B':[i for i in range(3)]})

df
```

Gives...

```
    A                                   B
0   2018-05-24 09:57:32.263331+00:00    0
1   2018-05-24 09:57:32.264331+00:00    1
2   2018-05-24 09:57:32.264331+00:00    2
```

A check on column 'A' shows all values to be Timestamp.

```
set((type(t) for t in df['A']))
{pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp}
```

Casting all columns to dtype='object'...
(*Why might I do this?  It happens automatically when joining columns of incompatible types, everything becomes object.  I'm forcing it here to show what happens to the content of the column.*)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({c:pd.Series(df[c].values, index=df.index, dtype='object') for c in df.columns})
df
```

Hmm... this looks different.

```
    A                           B
0   2018-05-24 09:57:32.263331  0
1   2018-05-24 09:57:32.264331  1
2   2018-05-24 09:57:32.264331  2
```

Checking 'A' again...

```
set((type(t) for t in df['A']))
{datetime.datetime}
```

...shows all the Timestamps in column 'A' have become datetime.datetime objects.
**Why has pandas decided not to use its own type?**

Worse, it's lost the timezone.  They're all now timezone naive datetimes at that.

```
(df['A'].iloc[0], df['A'].iloc[0].tzinfo)
(datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 24, 9, 57, 32, 263331), None)
```

Pandas 0.22 Python 3.6.3.

As pointed out by @user2285236 the problem isn't with pandas but with numpy.  Calling values (df[c].values) on the series of Timestamps extracts the underlying numpy array.  But the numpy array isn't an array of Timestamps, it's an array of datetimes without timezones (numpy doesn't do timezones).  The timezone info is stored in the pandas Series object representing the column so is lost by rebuilding the column in this way.

Comment: Why are you using `.values` in `c: pd.Series(df[c].values, `?

Comment: @user2285236 To force the recreation of the Series object from scratch.  It just digs out the underlying numpy array (afaik).

Comment: Yes but at that point these are no longer Timestamp objects. numpy doesn't have that type.

Comment: @user2285236 And I think you've put your finger on it.  That is where the conversion and the drop of the timezone occurs.